# On topological spaces, if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then for every sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $X$ with $x_n \to x$, then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces and let $f : X \to Y$ be a function and $x \in X$. I want to show that if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then every sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that $x_n \to x$ implies $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

This is my attempt:

**Proof:** Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, then for every $V \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ containing $f(x)$, there exists a $U \in \mathcal{T}_X$ containing $x$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $x_n \to x$. Then for every open $U \in \mathcal{T}_X$ containing $x$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geq N$. But this implies that for every open $V \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_n) \in f(U) \subset V$ for all $n \geq M$. Therefore, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ingredients are there, but I would expand the last step a bit to clarify what's going on:
For every $V\in\mathcal T_Y$ containing $f(x)$ there is some open $U$ such that $f(U)\subset V$. For this $U$, there is some $N$ such that $x_n\in U$ for all $n\ge N$, therefore $f(x_n)\in V$ for all $n\ge N$ (because all of $f(U)\subset V$).

Hence, wrapping this up: For every $V\in\mathcal T_Y$ there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $f(x_n)\in V$ for all $n\ge N$, having shown convergence of $(f(x_n))_n$.

In particular, $M=N$ in your proof.